# query_as! always show " expected `Option<String>`, found `String`" error

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I am trying to create an API endpoint (in Rust and sqlx) `GET /events/:id` which returns a record by querying a Postgres database from one events table for a given id (id type is uuid). The primary key of the events table is an autoincrement number and the filtering attribute is an "order_id". The table is as below.

| column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigint (primary key) |
| order_id | uuid |
| created | timestamp with time zone |
| user_id | character varying |

I keep getting this error when I try the below code. Please note I am not using `"SELECT *"` as I need only a selected set of attributes via this query. This is supposed to return a simple struct (named `EventEntity`)

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct EventEntity {
    pub order_id: Uuid,
    pub created: OffsetDateTime,
    pub user_id: Option<String>,
}
```

```
pub async fn find_by_id(db: &DbPool, id: &Uuid) -> Result<Self, ErrorResponse> {
    let res = query_as!(Self, "select order_id, created, user_id from events where order_id = $1", id)
        .fetch_one(db)
        .await?;

    Ok(res)
}
```

DbPool: `pub type DbPool = sqlx::Pool<Postgres>;`

The error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   |
79 |         let res = query_as!(Self, "select order_id, created, user_id from events where order_id = $1", id)
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Option<String>`, found `String`
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::option::Option<std::string::String>`
            found struct `std::string::String`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query` which comes from the expansion of the macro `query_as` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: try wrapping the expression in `Some`
   |
561|         Some($crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query!(record = $out_struct, source = $query, args = [$($args)*]))
   |         +++++
```

I have tried many sample code snippets similar to this but always end up getting this error. How can I correct this part of my code?

Answer (score 2):

I was corrected on this problem by one of my colleagues and the reason I kept getting this error is the mismatch of database table definition and the entity definition in code.

I had a `NOT NULL` user_id in the databae table and  `pub user_id: Option<String>,` in my struct. This was the conflict. Once I allowed `NULL` for the user_id column all is sorted and I am able to run the application.

If anyone runs into a similar problem, please check for the table definition and struct definition not only for the data types but also for the NULL constraints as well.